# Change actionbar to overlay from within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

I have a fragment (Fragment 1) that is replaced by another fragment (Fragment 2).  Fragment 1 is placed on the stack. I'm using compatibility mode (not ActionBarSherlock).

Here's my problem.  I want the actionbar to be displayed as overlay in some fragments, but not in others.  Specifically, when Fragment 2 is shown, I want it to appear in overlay and then go back to the normal actionbar once Fragment 2 exits.

Fragment 1 has an regular actionbar that is always visible.  But, when I replace Fragment 1 with Fragment 2, I need to hide the actionbar after 5 seconds.  If there is a touch event, the actionbar is shown again.  This all works fine, but, Fragment 2 is redrawn each time the actionbar is hidden or revealed.  Because of this, I want to make the actionbar in Fragment 2 show as an overlay.

I know I can change the actionbar overlay but I don't know how to do that programmatically from within the fragment.  I DON'T want to change it for every fragment, just Fragment 2.

Ideas?????

Comment: Actionbars are activity dependent not the solution for this may not be possible with the default actionbar you may want to just create your own actionbar like layout and then you will be able to have more control over it. I would reccommend this if you are just using the action bar as for a title bar

Comment: I understand that actionbars are activity dependent.  And I am using the actionbar for much more than a title bar.  What I'm thinking is if there is a way to change the acionbar from within the fragment by calling back into the main activity.  The problem is that I'd need to do that programmatically because it's too late to apply a change via themes (I think). ?????

Comment: If I understand all you want is to be able to modify the Action Bar from your fragment right?

Comment: That is correct.  I can add items to the acionbar.  What I need to know, is how to change the actionbar type to overlay.

Comment: Do you want to toggle its visibility? Changing in its visibility is quite easy. But making it overlay at run-time maybe a bit hard or tricky.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may not be the answer you were hoping for.

Consider a different question: Can we change activity theme after `setContentView(...)` has been called? The question has been asked many times, and a common solution is to recreate(calling `finish()` and `startActivity(getIntent())`) the activity and set the new theme before `setContentView(...)`.

Your question is an extension to this - with added complexity of changing the theme from a fragment. In any case, I don't consider the solution mentioned above a good one.

ActionBar is one of the first components to be initialized when an Activity is created. I don't think you will find a way to somehow 'refresh' it with new attributes. See below how the `requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)` method deals with post-setContentView(...) calls:

```
@Override
public boolean requestFeature(int featureId) {
    if (mContentParent != null) {
        throw new AndroidRuntimeException("requestFeature() must be 
                                                       called before adding content");
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

So, if `setContentView(...)` has already been called for the Activity (which it is, in your case), a runtime-exception will be thrown.

**Is it possible that you don't even require this functionality?**

Start by setting the ActionBar to be an overlay in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<!-- Support library attribute for compatibility -->
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

> Here's my problem. I want the actionbar to be displayed as overlay in some fragments...

Okay. We have already provisioned for this above.

> ... but not in others.

Say you don't want to have the ActionBar as an overlay in Fragment B. Then, in Fragment B's layout, do the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >  <<<-- ?attr/actionBarSize
                                                                    for compatibility

    ....
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

With the top-margin set to ActionBar's size, Fragment B looks as if it has a regular ActionBar - not an overlaid one. Another way to achieve this would be to have a `View` with `android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` placed as the first child in the layout above.

In essence:

- your ActionBar will be an overlay.
- in the fragments where the ActionBar will auto-hide, the fragments layout **will not** have any top-margin set.
- in the fragments where the ActionBar should not be overlaid, the fragments layout **will** have  top-margin set to `actionBarSize`.

**A point of note (thanks to `Jelle`)**:

If your `ActionBar` is semi-transparent, it would be best to use padding instead of margin for a consistent look.

Comment: I use this method as well. If your `LinearLayout` has a custom background, it might be better to use `paddingTop` instead of `marginTop`.

Comment: @Jelle Ah yes. You're right. If the actionbar is (semi)-transparent, your idea of using padding would work best. But if the actionbar has a opaque background/color, margin would be better - no overdraw. I'll edit my answer to include this. Thanks.

Comment: Nice thinking about the overdraw!

Comment: @JustLearningAgain You're welcome. Thanks for an interesting question & the bounty :).