# Can't figure out how to hook fling using ImageViewTouch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the library (https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) but I'm having a problem trying to figure out fling. I've read the other answers but they don't show the actual code used to get fling events.

I've hooked fling events like this:

```
 mImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
 {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
 }
 });
 gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), this));
```

MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener. I then override the onFling method.

The problem with this approach is that it disables the 1 touch and hence the pan functionality. I'm sure there is a better way to hook into fling events (so I can change images) but I'm not sure how -newb :(

What I'm looking for is a way to hook this similar to other hooks provided by ImageViewZoom.  Like this:

```
         mImage = (ImageViewTouch) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    mImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    // set the default image display type
    mImage.setDisplayType( ImageViewTouchBase.DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN );

    mImage.setSingleTapListener( new ImageViewTouch.OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSingleTapConfirmed()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            setToolbarsVisible(!isToolbarsVisible());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: I haven't tested/coded this myself, so it may not work out of the box.

I checked the source code for `ImageViewTouch` - it uses a `SimpleOnGestureListener` internally to provide various gesture-based functionality(including single-tap and double-tap hooks). It *doesn't* provide a callback for the fling event. So, you will have to code that yourself. Start by defining a new interface, say `OnImageViewTouchFlingEventListener` inside of/outside of `ImageViewTouch.java`. For example sake - define it after line 320 of `ImageViewTouch.java`:

```
public interface OnImageViewTouchFlingEventListener {

    // Can be defined as `void onFlingEvent(boolean left)` ==> if left==true, user
    // flinged `left-to-right`, else `right-to-left`. Similarly, you can
    // modify the parameters to add checks for up-to-down and down-to-up.
    void onFingEvent();
}
```

Next, add a member to `ImageViewTouch.java` after line 31:

```
private OnImageViewTouchFlingEventListener mFlingEventListener;
```

Add a public method to initialize `mFlingEventListener` after line 64:

```
public void setFlingEventListener( OnImageViewTouchFlingEventListener listener ) {
    mFlingEventListener = listener;
}
```

Line 261 of `ImageViewTouch.java`: The method `onFling(.....)` defines how the ImageView reacts to fling events. Firstly, check whether you agree with the current functionality. For example, you mentioned that you want the fling event to change images. If you look at line 266, the fling event will do nothing if the current scale is 1 - it simply returns false.

How the ImageView acts to a fling (and under what circumstances) is something that you will need to decide. Say, you decide that the fling will change images only when the scale is `one` - otherwise, it will pan. Then the following modification to line 266 should work:

```
if (getScale() == 1f) {
    if (mFlingEventListener != null) {
        mFlingEventListener.onFlingEvent();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your code, when you set an `OnTouchListener` on ImageViewTouch, it overtakes all touch functionality afforded by ImageViewTouch's internal touch/gesture handling - hence no single/double tap callbacks. This is why you cannot implement fling event callback outside of ImageViewTouch.java - well, you can - but then, you'll need to implement *everything other gesture* as well.

Changes to your activity code:

The member `mFlingEventListener` needs to be initialized:

```
mImage.setFlingEventListener(new ImageViewTouch.OnImageViewTouchFlingEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFlingEvent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFlingEvent fired");
        // handle change of image
    }
});
```

Comment: GREAT answer.  I was headed this way but I was hoping I missed something and could accomplish the functionality I wanted without modifying the ImageViewTouch code.  I think these changes should be put back into the original library.  Again... GREAT ANSWER!!!  Thanks for being so thorough.  Could you look at another question of mine that has a bounty?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945244/change-actionbar-to-overlay-from-within-fragment

Comment: @JustLearningAgain Thank you for the kind words. I looked through relevant source code regarding your other question. It seems that changing action bar to an overlay from a fragment isn't possible. See if the alternate solution that I have posted helps you any.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer you are looking for but I will give it a try. If you are not obliged to use the library you are currently using I would like to recommend this [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) which is the best zoomable image view solution I discovered so far. It has following features:

> ### Features
>
> - Out of the box zooming, using multi-touch and double-tap.
> - Scrolling, with smooth scrolling fling.
> - Works perfectly when using used in a scrolling parent (such as    ViewPager).
> - Allows the application to be notified when the displayed Matrix has    changed. Useful for when you need to update your UI based on the
>     current zoom/scroll position.
> - Allows the application to be notified when the user taps on the    Photo.