# Add/ remove ActionBar shadow from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

i have an activity where i am switching between fragments.

some fragments i want to have the action bar show in full, others i want it to be transparent.

i used the trick found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945244/change-actionbar-to-overlay-from-within-fragment), where i essentially have a theme that has:

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

and in my layouts where i want a static/ full action bar i'll add:

```
`layout_marginTop:"?android:attr/actionBarSize"`
```

in the fragments where i want a transparent action bar, i'll do:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

**the problem**: in the latter case, the action bar shadow still shows. i can disable it if i add:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

but now what about when i want the action bar to show in full/ non-transparent? i want the shadow to show with it as well. so is there a way to trigger that shadow on and off?

alternatively, i could just ditch the whole styling deal and just do:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show(); // or hide
```

and then in my layout i could manually add the back button that i want from the action bar. the issue in that case is that the action bar slides in and out and looks sloppy. i can't call:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

because it tells me:

> ActionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

so how can i add/remove the action bar shadow depending on which fragment is showing? or else, how can i hide the action bar without animation?

thanks!